# Creating html table from JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a an html file that has this snippet in it.

```
<div>
    <table id="apps"></table>
</div>
```

I am receiving JSON data that looks like this:

```
{
    "1": [
        {
            "A": "",
            "B": "",
            "C": "",
            "D": "",
            "E": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

There will be exactly one `"1"` , but there can be more than one dictionary within the list of `"1"`. In this example, we only have one `{}` within the list, `[]` , but there can exist multiple `{}` of containing exactly five items like what is shown above.

I want to create a table from this data, where each row represents a single `{}` within the `[]` and has five columns representing A, B, C, D, E respectively.

I am unsure if I should have the structure of this, the tags already in my html(this is not in my html code provided) and then populate these tags or should my function that loads this data in my html file, access table id="apps" and create these tags and then populate these tags? Which is better? and How might one accomplish this efficiently?

Comment: If this wasn't a homework assignment, I would strongly recommend jQuery DataTables as it does an excellent job of converting JSON data into a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this simple working example. I hope it will work as per your expectation.

```js
var dataObj = {
    "1": [{
            "A": "",
            "B": "",
            "C": "",
            "D": "",
            "E": ""
        },
        {
            "F": "",
            "G": "",
            "H": "",
            "I": "",
            "J": ""
        },
        {
            "K": "",
            "L": "",
            "M": "",
            "N": "",
            "O": ""
        }
    ]};

var dictionaryData = dataObj["1"];

for (var i in dictionaryData) {
  var table = document.getElementById("apps");
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  var td = document.createElement("td");
  
  for (var key in dictionaryData[i]) {
    var txt = document.createTextNode(key);
    td.appendChild(txt);
    tr.appendChild(td);
  }
  table.appendChild(tr);
}
```

```css
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <table id="apps"></table>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to fix your code, right now it's creating only one TD for each TR.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know your requirements for the project, but I would skip all that trouble and use a library like [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). There are many ways to populate a table from [AJAX](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/) or other [data sources](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/). Even if you are unable to tinker with table data source to comply with its standards, there is a [method](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) to reformat.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is "Which is better: having the table row and cell tags already in the markup, or build them as I get data?"

I would say the better option is to build the data as you get the objects.

In pseduocode:

```
for each object in 1
  make new row <tr></tr>

  for each data in object
    make new cell <td></td>
    insert data into <td>[here]</td>
    insert cell into <tr>[here]</tr>

  insert filled row into "apps" by using it's ID
done
```

Does this suffice for what you wanted to know?

Answer (score 0):

Check this demo:

```js
var jsonResponse = {
    "1": [{
            "A": "",
            "B": "",
            "C": "",
            "D": "",
            "E": ""
        },
        {
            "F": "",
            "G": "",
            "H": "",
            "I": "",
            "J": ""
        }
    ],
    "2": [{
            "K": "",
            "L": "",
            "M": "",
            "N": "",
            "O": ""
        },
        {
            "P": "",
            "Q": "",
            "R": "",
            "S": "",
            "T": ""
        }
    ]
};

$.each(jsonResponse, function(outerKey, list) {
    var row = $('<tr>', {
        id: 'row_' + outerKey
    });
    $.each(list, function(innerKey, value) {
        for (var key in value) {
            var col = $('<td>', {
                id: key,
                text: key
            })
            row.append(col);
        }
    });
    $('#apps').append(row);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <table id="apps"></table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROC SearchAllTables 
(
    @SearchStr nvarchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN

    CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
    SET  @TableName = ''
    SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

    WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName = ''
        SET @TableName = 
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
            FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
            WHERE       TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
                AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
                AND OBJECTPROPERTY(
                        OBJECT_ID(
                            QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                             ), 'IsMSShipped'
                               ) = 0
        )

        WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            SET @ColumnName =
            (
                SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
                FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE       TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                    AND TABLE_NAME  = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                    AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar')
                    AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
            )

            IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO #Results
                EXEC
                (
                    'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) 
                    FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                    ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
                )
            END
        END 
    END

    SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM #Results
 END


exec SearchAllTables @SearchStr='Canada'
```

Comment: Please look at your answer and edit it so that the code is properly formatted. I would edit myself but have no real idea which bits belong where.