# How to use data in table format for the email in node

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, html-table, nodemailer

I have simple JSON Data like this

```
 [ { labname: 'alcarediagnostics',
     date: '11-09-2019',
     count: '3230' },
    { labname: 'alcarediagnostics',
      date: '10-09-2019',
      count: '3341' },
    { labname: 'alcarediagnostics',
      date: '09-09-2019',
      count:'101'}]
```

I have to send this data in tabular format over the email.How can we do?

I have setup the code of the email

```
  let emailParams = {
    to: constant.emails,
    subject: subject,
    content: emailContent,
    contentType: "text/html",
    sender: { 
        name: '' , 
        email: '',
    }
};
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40419978/8053274

Comment: it's static data or dynamic?

Comment: It's dynamic data

Comment: You can use `.map(func)` to transform array elements, and `.join(delimiter)` to convert the array into a string. What exactly do you need help with? Do you know what an HTML table looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I have created some code hope this will help you...

```js
var data = [ { labname: 'alcarediagnostics',
     date: '11-09-2019',
     count: '3230' },
    { labname: 'alcarediagnostics',
      date: '10-09-2019',
      count: '3341' },
    { labname: 'alcarediagnostics',
      date: '09-09-2019',
      count:'101'}]
function CreateEmail()
{
 var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
 for (var key in data[0]) {
    var txt = document.createTextNode(key);
    let td = document.createElement("td");
    td.appendChild(txt);
    tr.appendChild(td);
  }
  table.appendChild(tr);
for (var i in data) {
 var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  
  let values =Object.values(data[i])
  for (var key in values) {
  let td = document.createElement("td");
    td.append(values[key])
    tr.append(td);
  }
  table.appendChild(tr);
  
}
debugger
let emailParams = {
    to: constant.emails,
    subject: subject,
    content: table.outerHTML,
    contentType: "text/html",
    sender: { 
        name: '' , 
        email: '',
    }
};

}
```

```css
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value='mail' onclick='CreateEmail()'>
```